# ASP.Net Core, My google chart won't display

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-visualization

Allright, so the issue I'm having is that my google chart wont display.I am fairly new to working with ASP.NET core applications, and I'm doing a school project. 
This is an example that works. I am trying to display data from a list that get it's data from a database, but I don't seem to get it to work.

This hardcoded data works fine:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Time', 'Data'],
                ['2004', 1000],
                ['2005', 1170],
                ['2006', 660],
                ['2007', 1030]
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Temperature',
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body class="container-fluid lead">
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i try to replace the hardcoded data with a foreach-loop it won't display. The page is just blank. This is my drawChart() with a foreach-loop.

```
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Time', 'Data'], 
                @foreach (var item in Model.measurementDataList)
                {
                   <text>['@item.TimeStamp', @item.MeasuredValue],</text>
                }

                ]);
```

I have displayed some data from the same database in a table. So the method I'm used to fill the list works. This is my method to getting the data from the database:

```
public List<MeasurementData> GetMeasurementData(string connectionString)
        {
            List<MeasurementData> measurementDataList = new List<MeasurementData>();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            string sqlQuery = "SELECT Timestamp, MeasuredValue FROM MEASUREDATA";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                MeasurementData measureParameter = new MeasurementData();

                measureParameter.TimeStamp = dr["Timestamp"].ToString();
                measureParameter.MeasuredValue = Convert.ToDouble(dr["MeasuredValue"]);

                measurementDataList.Add(measureParameter);
            }
            return measurementDataList;
        }
```

And here's the OnGet().

```
        public void OnGet()
        {
            SensorConfig sensorConfig = new SensorConfig();
            connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString");
            measurementDataList = sensorConfig.GetMeasurementData(connectionString); 
        }
```

view data source feature:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>MonitorLog - MonitoringApplication</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">MonitoringApplication</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/MonitorLog">Monitor log</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/SensorInformation">About Sensors</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Time', 'Data'], 

                ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Temperature',
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body class="container-fluid lead">
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - MonitoringApplication - <a href="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/site.js?v=dLGP40S79Xnx6GqUthRF6NWvjvhQ1nOvdVSwaNcgG18"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any output in F12?

Comment: Yes, In F12 I can find all the data.

Comment: If F12 source can find that ASP.NET Core has rendered your page and data correctly, the issue was not related to ASP.NET Core backend but your front-end javascript.

Comment: Again I'm farely new to this so after i looked ran the program again and checked for errorrs in F12 I found this.

"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row 1 has 3 columns, but must have 2
    at Object.gvjs_ql [as arrayToDataTable] (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:179)
    at drawChart (MonitorLog:48)", I don't have three colums in row 1.

Comment: Could you please share us your `rendered page` as `html` from your browser `view page source` feature? So we can find out if there is some JS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the mistake:

```js
@foreach (var item in Model.measurementDataList)
                {
                   <text>['@item.TimeStamp', @item.MeasuredValue],</text>
                }
```

Because if you render C# in cshtml directly, ASP.NET Core will HTML encode your script.

To make your app run, consider changing the script to

```js
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Time', 'Data'], 
                @foreach (var item in Model.measurementDataList)
                {
                   Html.Raw($"['{item.TimeStamp}', {item.MeasuredValue}],")
                }

                ]);
```

While this may solve your issue, rendering your data with C# to HTML is not a good practice.

I strongly suggest you writing an API that returns your data and you can write pure javascript to get the data.

Like this:

```js
$.get('/api/mychartdata', function(data) {
    google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
})
```

And the `data` is rendered as JSON from your ASP.NET Core Web API.

If you are not familiar with Web API, please read document here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Now, if I try to use the: `Html.Raw($"['{item.TimeStamp}', 'item.MeasuredValue']")`, I simply get that **Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string**. I will try to write the API, I'm not familiar with it, but it's an optional part of my project that I will try.

Comment: remove the single quotes from `MeasuredValue` --> `Html.Raw($"['{item.TimeStamp}', item.MeasuredValue]")`

Comment: That does not fix the problem I'm afraid. I still have the same error.

Comment: Could you please share with us your rendered page as HTML from your browser `view page source` feature? So we can find out if there is some JS issue.

Comment: I added the rendered page now in my main post.

Comment: As you can see, the reason why the rendered page doesn't work is the additional comma. Rendering JavaScript using C# is really a bad practice. Try using a web API now

Comment: So I managed to "fix" my issue. When I now look at the `view page source`, my data is there and it's rendered. But my graph won't appear. Any ideas why this happens?